# getting SSL connect error from git clone on red hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 (Santiago)

Tags: git, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I just installed version 2.22 of git on linux red hat enterprise release 6.7 (Santiago) and when I try to clone a repository I get the following SSL. connect error message:

$ git clone -b 6.7 https://codecloud.web.att.com/scm/st_scf/vas.git

Cloning into 'vas'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://codecloud.web.att.com/scm/st_scf/vas.git': SSL connect error.

Note1: the version of git is: 
2.22.0

Note2: I have installed git using yum package manager from the IUS for Enterprise Linux 6 repository.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated !

Best Regards,
Claudio

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 6.7 was released 2015-07-22, over five years ago.  git222 from IUS is built against the latest version of RHEL (and all included crypto libraries), which is currently RHEL 6.10.  It's likely that fully updating your system will get things working again.  If it doesn't, I'd suspect that there is a TLS mis-configuration with that remote host, as I can clone other repositories like GitHub without issue.